# Correct way to check if my TIdUDPServer is accessible from Internet?

Tags: delphi, networking, indy

I have created the Delphi application with `TIdUDPServer`. It listens on a specific port. I forwarded this port on the router programmatically, but I want to make sure my server is accessible from the Internet (from the outside).

Is it correct to use `TIdUDPClient` with the external IP address (I get it from a special website) and send `"hello"` to my server, which is in the same application?

I mean, what if the router will return this packet back without actually sending it to the Internet when it will see that the target IP of the packet is its own IP address?

Comment: "*what if the router will return this packet back without actually sending it to the Internet when it will see that the target IP of the packet is its own IP address?*" - that is certainly a possibility. To really be sure your server is accessible over the Internet, you would need to use a client that is running on another machine on the Internet side of your router (a friend's computer, a work computer, a mobile laptop/phone on a cellular network, etc).  Or, there are plenty of websites that can send test packets to a target server IP/port

Comment: Thanks Remy! This is exactly what I wanted to know.